Automatic extensions selection for VScode installation
I have a question about the setup of VSCode using the dev containers extension. When I installed vscode-remote-try-rust provided by Microsoft, "Japanese Language Pack for Visual Studio Code" was automatically detect, and installed on the container side.
I am not sure how this works. I am asking this question purely out of technical interest, but if anyone can help me, please answer.
I have checked the configuration files and scripts, but could not find the relevant part.

Certain technical details can only be answered by its original developers, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

I verified the installation flow of the extension and found that when the language pack is installed on the local side, it is automatically installed on the remote side (dev container volume) at the same time.
I could not identify the specific code, but I understood the behavior and it made sense to me.
